# Uncaught Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement in React Hooks. (Need to use Modal)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, modal-dialog, tailwind-css

Hi I am trying to make my news page in such a way that, when users click into a specific news, there would be a popup modal showing the full content of the news. However, the useModal in my map is causing the issue. Any suggestions on how can I work around it?
Here is my code:

```
import SortingDate from "@/functions/Sorting";
import { Posts } from "@/data/news-posts";
import { useModal } from "@nextui-org/react";
import NewsModal from "@/components/ui/news-modal";
import { useState, useEffect,  } from "react";
import Loading from "./loading";

function News() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetch("/api/news")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) return <Loading />;
  if (!data) return <Loading />;

  console.log(data);

  return (
    <div className="py-24">
      <div className="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div className="mx-auto max-w-2xl text-center">
          <h2 className="text-3xl font-bold tracking-tight text-white sm:text-4xl">
            Here comes the tea
          </h2>
          <p className="mt-2 text-lg leading-8 text-gray-300">
            Keep in touch with the latest news.
          </p>
        </div>

        {/* <Posts /> */}
        {/* {console.log(Res)} */}
        <div className="mx-auto mt-16 grid max-w-2xl grid-cols-1 gap-x-8 gap-y-20 lg:mx-0 lg:max-w-none lg:grid-cols-3">
          {SortingDate(data).map((post) => {
            const { setVisible, bindings } = useModal();
            return (
              <button
                onClick={() => setVisible((prevState) => !prevState)}
                key={post.id}
                className="flex flex-col items-start bg-gray-800 rounded-2xl"
              >
                <NewsModal
                  setVisible={setVisible}
                  bindings={bindings}
                  id={post.id}
                />
                <article key={post.id}>
                  <div className="relative w-full">
                    <img
                      src={post.imageUrl}
                      alt="Thumbnail"
                      className="aspect-[16/9] w-full rounded-2xl bg-gray-300 object-cover sm:aspect-[2/1] lg:aspect-[3/2]"
                    />
                    <div className="absolute inset-0 rounded-2xl ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-900/10" />
                  </div>
                  <div className="max-w-xl">
                    <div className="mt-8 flex items-center gap-x-4 text-xs mx-2">
                      <time dateTime={post.datetime} className="text-gray-300">
                        {post.date}
                      </time>
                      {/* <a
                    href={post.category.href}
                    className="relative z-10 rounded-full bg-gray-50 px-3 py-1.5 font-medium text-gray-600 hover:bg-gray-100"
                  >
                    {post.category.title}
                  </a> */}
                    </div>
                    <div className="group relative mx-2">
                      <h3 className="mt-3 text-lg font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-300 group-hover:text-gray-500">
                        <a href={post.href}>
                          <span className="absolute inset-0" />
                          {post.title}
                        </a>
                      </h3>
                      {/* <p className="mt-5 line-clamp-3 text-sm leading-6 text-gray-300">
                    {post.description}
                  </p> */}
                    </div>
                    <div className="relative mt-8 flex items-center gap-x-4 mx-2 my-2">
                      <div className="text-sm leading-6">
                        <p className="font-semibold text-white">
                          <a>
                            <span className="absolute inset-0" />
                            {post.author.name}
                          </a>
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </article>
              </button>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've tried putting my Loading conditions into useEffect, however I don't think it should be used like that.

Comment: Move the line `const { setVisible, bindings } = useModal();` to the beginning of the  `News` component block. React hooks can't be used inside `map` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good practice in this scenario is to take the code that you want to render inside the map function and create an another React component with it.

This can make your application code look much more cleaner, but will also let you avoid using the **useModal** hook inside the map function directly.

An implementation for what I have just mentioned will look like:

```js
export default function NewsButton({ post }) {
  const { setVisible, bindings } = useModal();

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => setVisible((prevState) => !prevState)}
      key={post.id}
      className="flex flex-col items-start bg-gray-800 rounded-2xl"
    >
      <NewsModal setVisible={setVisible} bindings={bindings} id={post.id} />
      <article key={post.id}>
        <div className="relative w-full">
          <img
            src={post.imageUrl}
            alt="Thumbnail"
            className="aspect-[16/9] w-full rounded-2xl bg-gray-300 object-cover sm:aspect-[2/1] lg:aspect-[3/2]"
          />
          <div className="absolute inset-0 rounded-2xl ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-900/10" />
        </div>
        <div className="max-w-xl">
          <div className="mt-8 flex items-center gap-x-4 text-xs mx-2">
            <time dateTime={post.datetime} className="text-gray-300">
              {post.date}
            </time>
            {/* <a
                      href={post.category.href}
                      className="relative z-10 rounded-full bg-gray-50 px-3 py-1.5 font-medium text-gray-600 hover:bg-gray-100"
                    >
                      {post.category.title}
                    </a> */}
          </div>
          <div className="group relative mx-2">
            <h3 className="mt-3 text-lg font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-300 group-hover:text-gray-500">
              <a href={post.href}>
                <span className="absolute inset-0" />
                {post.title}
              </a>
            </h3>
            {/* <p className="mt-5 line-clamp-3 text-sm leading-6 text-gray-300">
                      {post.description}
                    </p> */}
          </div>
          <div className="relative mt-8 flex items-center gap-x-4 mx-2 my-2">
            <div className="text-sm leading-6">
              <p className="font-semibold text-white">
                <a>
                  <span className="absolute inset-0" />
                  {post.author.name}
                </a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
    </button>
  );
}
```

```js
import SortingDate from "@/functions/Sorting";
import { Posts } from "@/data/news-posts";
import { useModal } from "@nextui-org/react";
import NewsModal from "@/components/ui/news-modal";
import { useState, useEffect,  } from "react";
import Loading from "./loading";

import NewsButton from '@/components/ui/news-button';

function News() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetch("/api/news")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) return <Loading />;
  if (!data) return <Loading />;

  console.log(data);

  return (
    <div className="py-24">
      <div className="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div className="mx-auto max-w-2xl text-center">
          <h2 className="text-3xl font-bold tracking-tight text-white sm:text-4xl">
            Here comes the tea
          </h2>
          <p className="mt-2 text-lg leading-8 text-gray-300">
            Keep in touch with the latest news.
          </p>
        </div>

        {/* <Posts /> */}
        {/* {console.log(Res)} */}
        <div className="mx-auto mt-16 grid max-w-2xl grid-cols-1 gap-x-8 gap-y-20 lg:mx-0 lg:max-w-none lg:grid-cols-3">
          {SortingDate(data).map((post) => {
            return <NewsButton post={post}/>
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```